# Should I change the structure of my .Net MVC app when using Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, structure

In my current development models, I typically use the following solution structure:

```
  D     
  a 
  t ---- Presentation (MVC, WCF, WPF)
  a            |
    --- Business Logic
  M            |            
  o ----- Data Access (Repositories & Unit of Work)
  d            |
  e ------- Entities (EF or nHibernate)
  l
  s
```

I know there are arguments that EF IS your repository and UOW, but I've found that keeping them out of your business logic is still advantagious.

I'm starting to move my development efforts to focus more on using Azure.  I will be re-factoring a couple of my web apps to use Azure.

I wondered if there was any compelling reason to re-think the way I'm structuring my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions that you might keep in mind while porting your application towards Azure:

1. **What is the reason to port your application to Azure?** If you are really aiming at scalability, you might really need a loosely coupled distributed application. It is not clear *if your current architecture is a really one of a distributed application* of not, e.g. if all your layers have to be hosted on a single machine or coupled so loosely that can be distributed over several processing units. In case of Azure you'll have to adapt your architecture to be at least aware of distributed environment, e.g. handle time-outs or connection/messages losses between single layers. And yes, if you want a *robust communication between every layer*, you will have to do something explicitly for it (using messages with [queues](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/queue-service/) or [service bus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsazure/ee732537.aspx) etc.)
2. **What about security?** How do users (if there are any) authenticate themselves in your application? You might want to use [Azure AD Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/aad.aspx), [run you own AD controller on a Virtual Machine](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/active-directory-forest/) or make your on-premises AD controller available for your instance (that might be somewhat tricky).
3. **What is the ultimate data storage you are using?** Depending upon the type of this storage (relational database, non-relational database etc.) you might want to use SQL Azure as RDBMS for your data or run [MongoDB in the cloud](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/deploy-mongodb-worker-roles-in-azure/), or [maybe table and blob storage would do](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-US/home/features/data-management/). Again, one has to keep that in mind (and configure retry and time-out policies for EF, for example).
4. **What is your hosting model and level of virtualization?** Depending upon the desired level of virtualization -- from Iaas to PaaS -- you might need to keep in mind that your application might be shut down and re-spawned at any arbitrary time point with all your local drive storage completely reset. Therefore if you rely on some (temporarily) locally stored data, you might want to change your storage mechanism to one provided by Azure (like BLOB or table storage).